# How do I get commerce_message to send order fullfilment message?

Tags: commerce

I have installed commerce_message and cloned the 'send order email'. It gets fired, but no 'message' gets saved in field_data_field_message_rendered_body and no message gets sent.

The rule does get triggered. Turning on 'log all warnings and errors, sending it to the 'system log' and doing drush ws --full --tail I find that the rule is being run.

```
Rule Commerce order message: admin order e-mail  fires. [edit]
0 ms Rule Commerce order message: admin order e-mail  fires.
2.046 ms Evaluating the action entity_create. [edit]
2.478 ms Added the provided variable entity_created of type message [edit]
2.93 ms Evaluating the action data_set. [edit]
3.254 ms Evaluating the action entity_save. [edit]
3.334 ms Saved entity_created of type message.
21.324 ms Evaluating the action message_notify_process. [edit]
195.957 ms Rule Commerce order message: admin order e-mail  has fired.
```

The rule is

```
{ "commerce_message_commerce_message_admin_order_e_mail_" : {
"LABEL" : "Commerce order message: admin order e-mail ",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"WEIGHT" : "3",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"TAGS" : [ "Commerce Checkout" ],
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "message_notify", "commerce_checkout" ],
"ON" : { "commerce_checkout_complete" : [] },
"DO" : [
  { "entity_create" : {
      "USING" : {
        "type" : "message",
        "param_type" : "commerce_order_order_confirmation",
        "param_user" : [ "commerce-order:owner" ]
      },
      "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
    }
  },
  { "data_set" : {
      "data" : [ "entity-created:message-commerce-order" ],
      "value" : [ "commerce-order" ]
    }
  },
  { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "entity-created" ], "immediate" : 1 } },
  { "message_notify_process" : {
      "message" : [ "entity-created" ],
      "save_on_fail" : "0",
      "save_on_success" : "0",
      "mail" : "[site:mail]"
    }
  }
]
}
}
```

A clone of the default rule I get with commerce message.

Nothing happens as a result though. I would like to send the shop owners a note that the order has been checked out and they should do something with it. Ideally with some order details in the message.

The only complications I can think of is that we have mailmime, mimemail htmlmail (for other modules) and messaging_htmlmail.

I am getting the 'account creation' email.

Comment: Are mail system are you using for sending mails?

Comment: Yes - MimeMailSystem is the default class.

Comment: If you're using Commerce Message along with the rules and the rules are firing, then you're likely looking at some problem with your host or with your hosting configuration. You'll need to look outside of Drupal for this issue.

Comment: I am testing it on the local machine. macos with postfix and a rule that says 'all local mail redirect to me'.  I get billy mail invoice, I can see the maillog entry for that but not commerce_message.